# Why does my pandas filters work in separate steps but not in one command?

Tags: python, pandas, filter, slice

I'm having problems filtering my pandas dataframe in one command.  For instance, the following multi-step filter works perfectly:

```
check2020 = check[check['effyear'] == '2020']
check2020_can = check2020[check2020['canceled'] == 'Y']
check2020_can_6 = check2020_can[check2020_can['decile'] == 6]
check2020_can_6_p_s = check2020_can_6[(check2020_can_6['usage'] == 'P') | (check2020_can_6['usage'] == 'S')]
```

But if I were to do the following:

```
check[(check['effyear'] == '2020') & (check['canceled'] == 'Y') & (check['decile'] == 6) & (check['usage'] == 'P') | (check['usage'] == 'S')]
```

Then I get 30,000 more observations that do not all follow the filter.  Is the all in one filter not structured correclty?

Comment: ) &`(` (check['usage'] == 'P') | (check['usage'] == 'S')`)` you need to group them since `A&B|C` is different than `A&(B|C)` which is `A&B|A&C`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need extra pair of parenthesis:

```
check[(check['effyear'] == '2020') & 
      (check['canceled'] == 'Y') & 
      (check['decile'] == 6) & 
      ((check['usage'] == 'P') | (check['usage'] == 'S')) # () here
     ]
```

Also, use `isin` for better syntax:

```
check[(check['effyear'] == '2020') & 
      (check['canceled'] == 'Y') & 
      (check['decile'] == 6) & 
      check['usage'].isin(['P', 'S'])  # this
     ]
```